Getting a "The file for this url was not found" error on tus/server
I have a @tus/server backend with a react uppy frontend. And when uploading I'm getting this response
"The file for this url was not found"
Im runnin multiple containers and the vps is behind nginx.
In the frontend I'm using uppy like this
const [uppy] = useState(() => new Uppy().use(Tus, { endpoint: 'https://app.chatzu.ai/files/' }));
the frontend does these requests in order
Request URL:
https://app.chatzu.ai/files
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:
<IP>
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin


Request URL:
https://app.chatzu.ai/files/
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
<IP>
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Nginx conf

    location /files/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:1080;
     # Disable request and response buffering
        proxy_request_buffering  off;
        proxy_buffering          off;
        proxy_http_version       1.1;

        # Add X-Forwarded-* headers
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_set_header         Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header         Connection "upgrade";
        client_max_body_size     0;

}

and my tus server code
const { Server } = require('@tus/server');
const { FileStore } = require('@tus/file-store');
const express = require('express');

const host = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 1080;
const app = express();
const uploadApp = express();

const server = new Server({
  path: '/files',
  datastore: new FileStore({ directory: '/files' }),
});

// Middleware to log all incoming requests
uploadApp.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`);
  next(); // Pass control to the next middleware or route handler
});

uploadApp.all('*', server.handle.bind(server));
app.use('/files', uploadApp);

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`);
});

Thanks

From the location nginx directive documentation:

If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI and location could be defined like this:
location /user/ {
    proxy_pass http://user.example.com;
}

location = /user {
    proxy_pass http://login.example.com;
}


Your POST request to /files URI get redirected using the 301 Moved Permanently HTTP redirect to /files/. Being redirected with 301 or 302 HTTP redirects, browsers usually changes any other request method to GET, discarding the request body (you need to use 307 or 308 HTTP redirects in order to prevent this). I think your options are to change upload path from /files to /files/ in your node.js server code (better) or to change location URI from /files/ to /files in your nginx config (worse).
